# Sensu reports Found 0 matching processes for tomcat8

Tags: ruby, sensu

I am getting the following error

```
CheckProcess CRITICAL: Found 0 matching processes; cmd //usr/bin/java * -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat8 */
```

My `config.json` has the following check

```
 "command": "check-process.rb --pattern \"/usr/bin/java * -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat8 *\" -W 1",
```

My `ps -ef | grep tomcat` gives the following

```
ubuntu   23100     1  0 Oct07 ?        00:01:32 /usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat8/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -classpath /opt/tomcat8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat8/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat8 -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat8/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Ruby regular expression is wrong. You forgot to escape the `/` and the `*` needs `.` before them to denote which caracters there can be any of.

It should be:

```
\/usr\/bin\/java .* -Dcatalina.base=\/opt\/tomcat8 .*
```

I use http://rubular.com/ to test my expressions before using them.